# Ribbon bar designer shows empty ribbon control for VSTO Excel Application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon

I have a C# add-in that I am developing in Visual Studio 2019.

- I have a single custom ribbon control that appears as a new tab in Excel whenever I run the add-in.
- The `NBWRibbon01.Designer.cs` contains code for the custom ribbon groups and buttons shown below.
- The application builds and runs without error.

[image: Custom Ribbon that appears when the Excel Add-in is run.]

However, when I launch the Designer for the same custom ribbon in Visual Studio 2019, I get an empty ribbon bar control shown below.

[image: Ribbon Designer for the same Ribbon Bar in Visual Studio 2019]

Has anyone encountered this issue?  I am guessing that I will need to completely re-create the ribbon bar from scratch.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi Eugene - no errors.  I can do a Clean and Rebuild All. When I run, Excel launches and shows the CLIR dB ribbon bar  as shown above.  If I view the CLIR dB ribbon bar in the WinForms designer, I get the empty ribbon.  I don't want to save anything in the designer as it would wipe out the existing ribbon.  I'm thinking that the only thing to do is start a new ribbon from scratch and transplant.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the VSTO design-time adapter add-in is enabled in Excel.

[image: VSTO design-time adapter add-in]

Also check out the code-behind files, most probably any of them was edited to ruin the ribbon designer.

The Ribbon designer is good as a starting point in Visual Studio. But it doesn't support all the features that the Fluent UI provides. So, I'd suggest moving to the raw XML markup. You can design the base UI using the ribbon designer in Visual Studio and then export the custom markup to the ribbon XML. Read more about that in the [How to: Export a ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) article.

Comment: I was able to open a version of the source code prior to putting the solution on DevOps.  I can edit the ribbon bar in the backup.  Something occurred while migrating the files to Dev.Azure.com (not sure what - this is why we keep backups).

Comment: I copied the files from my backup into my Source\Repo folder and have the toolbar back in the Designer.  This seemed to fix the issue, however, when I try to drag a control to the designer, I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in Visual Studio.

Comment: Added the control by manually edition the NBWRibbon01.Designer.cs file.  Once you do a build, the designer can be used to flesh out the newly added controls.